# Upgrading to Tomcat 8 breaks MultipartFile upload

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat8

I'm using Spring Boot. The method I'm calling in my controller looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{customerId}/files/{id}/addFile", method = RequestMethod.POST,
        produces = "application/json; charset=UTF-8")
@ResponseBody
public Response uploadFile(@PathVariable String customerId, @PathVariable String id,
        @RequestParam("uploadedFile") MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
```

After upgrading to Tomcat 8 I'm getting the following error when calling this method. I set a breakpoint on the first line which is never reached.:

> org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request
>   processing failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Could not parse
>   multipart servlet request; nested exception is java.io.IOException:
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadException: Stream
>   closed

Has anyone come across this issue?

Comment: Can u post your pom.xml or whatever config for your build tool.

Comment: I can't post my pom.xml but I can confirm that this started happening when my parent pom upgraded the following:

spring-boot 1.1.5.RELEASE to 1.1.8.RELEASE
&
tomcat 7.0.54 to 8.0.12

Comment: Have you tried with a more up-to-date version of Tomcat 8? 8.0.20 is the latest at the time of writing. Also, there's a [getting started guide](https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-uploading-files) for uploading files with Spring Boot. It works fine with Tomcat 8. Perhaps you can look at the guide and figure out what's different in your app.

Comment: I have tried Tomcat 8.0.20 but am running into the same issue. The controller in the guide looks to be doing the same thing I am above. :/ Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add multipart.maxFileSize and multipart.maxRequestSize to your application.properties file. SpringBoot seems to has a default value of 128KB, which broke my upload.

Comment: It's worth mentioning if making the suggested changes worked for you when you faced the same problem.

Comment: Sorry I was thinking, that the add of multipart.maxFileSize and multipart.maxRequestSize fixed my problem, but in fact it didn't. The only solution was to downgrade spring-boot-autoconfigure to version 1.2.1 You can find the same issue [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2862)

Comment: Now I've found a solution for my problem, besides downgrading spring-boot-autoconfigure.
 I created a MultipartConfigElement Bean, where I set the Multipart location.